# Which is the most idiomatic way to parse an i32 from ascii in Rust

Tags: parsing, rust, vector

I'm trying to find both the quickest and the most idiomatic way(s) to parse an i32 from a vector containing Ascii in Rust. I have three functions (minus error handling etc):

```rs
#![feature(test)]

extern crate test;

fn v_0() -> i32 {
    let read_buf: Vec<u8> = vec![54, 52, 52];
    let num: i32 = String::from_utf8(read_buf)
        .unwrap()
        .parse()
        .unwrap();

    assert_eq!(num, 644);
    num
}

fn v_1() -> i32 {
    let read_buf: Vec<u8> = vec![54, 52, 52];

    let num: i32 = read_buf.iter().rev().enumerate().map(|(idx, val)| {
        (val - 48) as i32 * 10.pow(idx) 
    }).sum();

    assert_eq!(num, 644);
    num
}

fn v_2() -> i32 {
    use atoi::atoi;

    let read_buf: Vec<u8> = vec![54, 52, 52];
    let num = atoi(read_buf[..].try_into().unwrap()).unwrap();

    assert_eq!(num, 644);
    num
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use test::Bencher;

    use crate::{v_0, v_1, v_2};

    #[bench]
    fn v_0_bench(b: &mut test::Bencher) {
        let n = test::black_box(1000);
        b.iter(v_0)
    }

    #[bench]
    fn v_1_bench(b: &mut test::Bencher) {
        let n = test::black_box(1000);
        b.iter(v_1)
    }

    #[bench]
    fn v_2_bench(b: &mut test::Bencher) {
        let n = test::black_box(1000);
        b.iter(v_2)
    }
}
```

And the benchmark results are as follows:

```
test tests::v_0_bench ... bench:          16 ns/iter (+/- 0)
test tests::v_1_bench ... bench:           0 ns/iter (+/- 0)
test tests::v_2_bench ... bench:          11 ns/iter (+/- 1)
```

I'm suspecting that the v_1 bench is getting optimized away, so as a question within a question, how do I prevent this?

Out of the 3 example functions, if any, which should one use and why?

Comment: The vector creations/destructions are in the benchmarks. I would recommend passing a slice on a previously created vector.

Comment: Good catch. Will update now.

Comment: You're not using `black_box()` properly.

Comment: Just followed this guide: https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.12.1/book/benchmark-tests.html

What's the proper way?

Comment: From proper benchmarking with criterion with this code: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e0d95b70f3d054332683e527a7da40e5, `simple()` is consistently the fastest (probably because it doesn't check for invalid input), then `atoi()`, then the other two.

Comment: From personal experience, atoi is not the fastest, it's usually always the standard library implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Playing around this on my computer gives the following results.

```
test tests::v_0_bench ... bench:       1,126 ns/iter (+/- 27)
test tests::v_1_bench ... bench:         767 ns/iter (+/- 12)
test tests::v_2_bench ... bench:       1,728 ns/iter (+/- 4)
test tests::v_3_bench ... bench:         424 ns/iter (+/- 2)
test tests::v_4_bench ... bench:         438 ns/iter (+/- 2)
```

The buffer has been removed from the benchmark and `black_box()` is used in order to pretend the parameter is unpredictable and the result is used.
The sequence of bytes has been made longer in order to let the algorithms actually work, and the invocations are repeated many times in order to introduce bigger differences in the results.

Comparing `v_0` and `v_1` shows that a substantial part of the time is spent in checking the utf8 string.
`v_2` is probably disappointing because of its `pow()` operation.
`v_3` is clearly faster, but it does not check anything; the result could be meaningless because the bytes could contain anything but digits, and the resulting integer may also overflow if the sequence is too long!
`v_4` is similar to `v_3` but considers an eventual starting `-` sign (because an `i32` is expected, not an `u32`); this first check does not seem to be too detrimental to performances.

If we are absolutely certain that the sequence of bytes is correct, then we could lean towards the fastest version (`v_3` or `v_4`), but in any other situation we should [definitely prefer](https://www.reddit.com/r/Jokes/comments/5g2ay4/interviewer_i_heard_you_were_extremely_quick_at/) `v_0`.

```rust
#![feature(test)] // cargo bench
extern crate test; // not in Cargo.toml

#[inline(always)]
fn v_0(buf: &[u8]) -> i32 {
    std::str::from_utf8(buf).unwrap().parse().unwrap()
}

#[inline(always)]
fn v_1(buf: &[u8]) -> i32 {
    unsafe { std::str::from_utf8_unchecked(buf) }
        .parse()
        .unwrap()
}

#[inline(always)]
fn v_2(buf: &[u8]) -> i32 {
    buf.iter()
        .rev()
        .enumerate()
        .map(|(idx, val)| (val - b'0') as i32 * 10_i32.pow(idx as u32))
        .sum()
}

#[inline(always)]
fn v_3(buf: &[u8]) -> i32 {
    buf.iter().fold(0, |acc, b| acc * 10 + (b - b'0') as i32)
}

#[inline(always)]
fn v_4(buf: &[u8]) -> i32 {
    let mut it = buf.iter();
    let b0 = *it.next().unwrap();
    let init = if b0 == b'-' { 0 } else { (b0 - b'0') as i32 };
    let num = it.fold(init, |acc, b| acc * 10 + (b - b'0') as i32);
    if b0 == b'-' {
        -num
    } else {
        num
    }
}

fn make_buf() -> Vec<u8> {
    b"1234567890".to_vec()
}

#[inline(always)]
fn run(
    mut f: impl FnMut(&[u8]) -> i32,
    buf: &[u8],
) {
    for _ in 0..100 {
        test::black_box(f(test::black_box(buf)));
    }
}

#[bench]
fn v_0_bench(b: &mut test::Bencher) {
    let buf = make_buf();
    b.iter(|| run(v_0, &buf))
}

#[bench]
fn v_1_bench(b: &mut test::Bencher) {
    let buf = make_buf();
    b.iter(|| run(v_1, &buf))
}

#[bench]
fn v_2_bench(b: &mut test::Bencher) {
    let buf = make_buf();
    b.iter(|| run(v_2, &buf))
}

#[bench]
fn v_3_bench(b: &mut test::Bencher) {
    let buf = make_buf();
    b.iter(|| run(v_3, &buf))
}

#[bench]
fn v_4_bench(b: &mut test::Bencher) {
    let buf = make_buf();
    b.iter(|| run(v_4, &buf))
}

fn main() {
    let buf = make_buf();
    println!("v_0 {}", v_0(&buf));
    println!("v_1 {}", v_1(&buf));
    println!("v_2 {}", v_2(&buf));
    println!("v_3 {}", v_3(&buf));
    println!("v_4 {}", v_4(&buf));
}
/*
v_0 1234567890
v_1 1234567890
v_2 1234567890
v_3 1234567890
v_4 1234567890
*/
```

Comment: I believe `v_4()` is good enough for when you don't need validation, but note that your handling of `-` is slightly suboptimal: multiplication is expensive, so it is faster to check twice for sign: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1028af7be357da2400ef0da7f3d330ef. This brings this version equal to without check.

Comment: Actually, my sign handling is consistently slightly _faster_ than no handling of the sign, both with test::Bencher and criterion. Not sure why...

Comment: I've just realized out code is subtly incorrect: it'll product an incorrect result for `i32::MIN`. Think why.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Ah yes, good catch, the absolute value of signed integers can go one unit further in the negative part...

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I tried your version with multiple checks of `buf[0]` and it is indeed a bit faster on my computer too. I thought that this would have implied multiple bound checks (that's why we prefer iterators in general), but I guess the compiler is smart enough to check only once.